# how get value function in variable

Tags: javascript

Hello me need get variable from function 
me return in answer undefined

```js
function etr() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = paramsImg;
  img.src = picFile.result;

  function paramsImg() {
    return img.height;
  };
};


var vvvr = etr();
alert(vvvr);
```

Comment: You get `undefined` because `etr` has no `return` statement.

Comment: `etr()` does not return anything. Therefore, `alert (etr())` (or similar) will always be `undefined`,

Comment: What output do you expect?

Comment: Please take some time to read [ask] then edit the question with a proper explanation of what it is you are expecting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `etr` doesn't return anything. I see that you are trying to return from an event handler for onload, but that only returns from the `paramsImg` function and not from `etr` (which has already returned before the image loads). You should wither make `etr` accept a callback function or return a Promise so that you can alert the images height ***after*** the image has loaded. Here is an example with a Promise:

```js
function etr() {
  return new Promise( ( resolve, reject ) => {
    var img = new Image();
    img.onload = _ => resolve(img.height);
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.src = picFile.result;
  } );
};

var picFile = { result: 'https://dummyimage.com/600x1234/000/fff' };

(async function ( ) {
  var vvvr = await etr();
  alert(vvvr);
})( );
```

Answer (score 2):

```
function etr() {
  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = paramsImg;
  img.src = picFile.result;

  function paramsImg() {
    return img.height;
  };
};
```

1. In your function, you mentioned paramsImg before its even loaded, so its not visible to img.onload.
2. paramsImg is declared simply as function, its not have scope outside the object. You need to use this keyword or mention fn with prototype.

```js
function etr(picFile){  
  
  this.paramsImg = function(){
    return img.height;
  };              

  var img = new Image();
  img.onload = this.paramsImg;
  img.src = picFile.result;
}

picfile = {
  result: 10
}



var vvvr = new etr(picfile);
alert(vvvr.paramsImg());
```